# Changing localhost to public IP in a VM

Tags: django, ip, virtual-machine, virtualenv, read-the-docs

I am testing RTD to build our API docs implementation, so running a local installation of RTD in a virtualenv within a debian VM. The ./manage.py runserver command runs the RTD server successfully.

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
March 25, 2015 - 03:11:57
Django version 1.6.10, using settings 'settings.sqlite'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

To access the RTD admin console from my laptop browser (outside the VM) I would like to change the localhost to the public IP. For that, I changed the IP references in:

- /etc/hosts
- settings/sqlite.py (section
  Internal_ips, and a few other occurrences)

But, it continues to build the server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Where should I be configuring this? What else should I be doing?

Answer (score 2):

*RESOLVED*

Run the RTD server as:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

OR

```
./manage.py runserver [VM IP ADDRESS]:8000
```